# How to stringify the value of a variable?

Tags: c++, string, stdmap, stdstring, std-pair

Let's say we've got `int abc=123;`

I want to stringify both the variable name and the value. But using a macro like `#define n(x) #x` only stringifies the variable name itself. How can I stringify the value along with the variable name and efficiently **access them together**?

Comment: What type does `x` have? There's no single way to stringify an object.

Comment: You have to write C++ code to do it. C++ will not do it for you. The only thing that C++ knows how to format are character strings, and numeric values. For anything else, you have to write the code that does that.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `x` is a string. But I want to define a new variable that takes `x`'s value as its variable name. Let's say `string x="abc";` How can I define `string abc` without directly defining it?

Comment: That is not possible. A variable's name is completely fixed during compilation after the preprocessor runs. At runtime, there is no concept at all of a variable's name, and there simply is no way to alter an existing variable's name or create a new named variable at runtime. This tends to be possible in languages that have constructs like `eval`, but not in C++. It would help to know what problem you are trying to solve. Perhaps [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) would be useful, for example using `std::map<std::string, std::string>`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing them together in a `std::map` would do this.

```
#define n(x) #x
int abc=123;
std::map<std::string,std::string> f;
f[n(abc)]=std::to_string(abc);
```

Now `f["abc"] == "123"` and this was what I wanted to do. Thanks for previous help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to guarantee that the parameter of your stringify macro is an existing variable, you can do something like:

```
#define VAR2STR(x) var2str(x, #x)
template<class T> std::string var2str(const T& var, char* s) {return s;}
```